# Text editor on trilogy sites really SHOULD convert TABs to spaces!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tabs-to-spaces

I know this has been discussed before - but to no avail, it seems.

I think the text editor on the trilogy sites **URGENTLY** needs to convert TABs that users paste in to spaces, if it cannot handle tabs properly.

It's annoying and very time consuming to try and wade through lots of long posts of mostly newbies who don't know this (yet), and try and fix this up. It's quite annoying when it happens to me when I paste something, too......

To me, this is a #1 highest priority item - why isn't this being handled?? I requested this in August 09 - and it seems, nothing has happened since.

Doesn't anyone else feel annoyed by this lack of TABs, or lack of converting tabs to spaces on pasting in code snippets and tabular data??

Comment: @Shog9 Is it really status-completed? I have seen some posts with tabs instead of spaces these days a lot :(

Comment: @oscar: got a link? Also, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89730/convert-tabs-to-spaces-actually-status-completed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often post text from my programming editor into an answer, go Gah! go back to the editor, replace tabs with spaces and then paste again. So I'd really like tab replacement. Or more sensible tabs - a user preference for this, which allowed you to to specify the tab size in spaces, would be very nice.

Comment: +1 for tab replacement, -1 for the user preference :)

Answer (score 3):

The server-side markdown parser does normalize tabs to spaces.

View source on it yourself and see..

http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/

Comment: I don't seem to actually see this in action, though! Seems so many posts, people put in TABs and their tabular display gets all messed up.......

Comment: @marc_s I agree. [I edit many posts](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor?userid=342852) and I convert tabs to spaces manually in many posts every day